# How to make Marsaglia polar method return values [0, 1)?

Tags: random-generation, normal-distribution

I've implemented the [Marsaglia polar method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) to generate random numbers that are normally distributed. Unfortunately the code as shown on this [website](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html) returns numbers that are not within the range [0, 1).

Code:

```
     double x1, y1, w;

     do {
             x1 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
             y1 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
             w = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
     } while ( w >= 1.0 || w == 0 );

     w = sqrt( (-2.0 * ln( w ) ) / w );
     return x1 * w;
```

where ranf() returns values [0, 1).

For example, if (x1, y1) was (-0.43458512585358, -0.07521858582050478), this returns a value of -1.7830255550765148. Obviously not a value within my expected range.

I've seen some implementations that multiplies this by the standard deviation and adds the mean. But if I want to get numbers that range from [0, 1), what should I use as my standard deviation and mean? currently, I'm using a standard deviation of 1/8.125 ~= 0.121212... and 0.5 as the mean, but I've only stumbled on this by experimentation. What is the official way for me to get this appropriately ranged?

To answer the question in the comments below: I want to generate normal random variables within the range 0 and 1. Obviously I'd like the mean to be at 0.5 and values no be distributed around this mean.

More for my enlightenment, will the polar method really return numbers over the entire real line? If so, then it should be easy for me to scale the result down to [0, 1), assuming I don't hit floating point underflow due to the division to scale things down.

New edit:
What I'm trying to do is take Aniko's advise in his answer to my other [Power Factor Problem question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/applied-statistics-to-find-the-minimum-load-for-power-factor-floor). So my first thought was that simulate my distribution of velocities, was to implement my on GaussianRandom class by deriving from [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts6se2ek.aspx) and overriding [Random.Sample()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.sample.aspx) and the 3 other methods as recommended by MSDN. Since Random.Sample() is suppose to return a double in the range [0, 1), then I've hit this stumbling block.

I've come to the same conclusion as mbq's answer after staring at the ln(x) graph where x is in (0, 1] and sqrt(x) where x is in (0, 2].

From a practical/programming standpoint, I can't override Random.Sample(), because later when I actually call GaussianRandom.NextDouble(), there is no way for me to pass in the actual standard deviations for my velocities. It looks like I'll have to use the Marsaglia polar method in the raw instead of wrapped within the Random class. My "cartridge" generator will have to `return x1 * w * stdDev + mean`.

Comment: Do you want to generate normal random variables truncated to range between 0 and 1 or uniform random variables between 0 and 1? The Marsagla polar method will return numbers over the entire real line as it generates standard normal random variables.

Comment: I don't know if this solves your problem, but you might wanna take a look at this question where some transformations that squash everything between 0 and 1 are discussed: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/how-to-represent-an-unbounded-variable-as-number-between-0-and-1/1113#1113

Comment: @Ants: "Scaling down" from the real line to an interval will necessarily make the resulting generator non-Normal.

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks. I'll have to remember some of those tricks for future reference.

Comment: Your clarification completely confused me. You plan to generate a random normal variable `x1` truncated to the 0-1 range, then plug it into the `x1 * w * stdDev + mean` formula (what is `w`?) to get a normal with mean `mean` and standard deviation `stdDev`? If so, that's totally wrong. Just take a standard normal `z`, and calculate `mean + z*stdDev` to get a non-standard normal variable.

Comment: @Aniko: I was just using 'w' because that's what code that I grabbed had. I should have renamed it 'r2' to represent r-squared during the looping, and then added a new variable 'transform' for the 'w' in the second to the last line in the original code. When I gave up trying to get a return value from 0-1, I resorted to <code>x1 * w * stdDev + mean<code> but the code is not used in the context of overriding Random.Sample() anymore. How do I get <code>z<code> given the Marsaglia polar method?

Comment: Sorry, I did not scroll up to the code. Now I see what `x1` and `w` are. Mea culpa. Then using `x1 * w * stdDev + mean` is correct (`z` is `x1*w`). I still don't get the part about having to have the result to be between 0 and 1, but I see that you are happy with mbq's answer, so I am happy to live with my confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just impossible, since normal distribution has nonzero probability for the whole $R$. Of course because of the numerical issues it would be not the case for Marsaglia method (this obviously means that it is not creating normally distributed numbers), yet this numerical range is so huge that it is nonsense to scale it to [0,1].

EDIT: So, as long as I understand, you want this number to be in [0,1) to overload .net Random; you don't need to! Write your own class, say NormalRandom which will hold one Random object and will use its output to generate (using Marsaglia) normal random numbers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and just use them. Or rather use something already done; Google found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Random.aspx .
On margin, remember that when it is said that something which cannot be negative is "normally distributed" (for instance mass) it does mean that it is not from normal but from "almost-normal" distribution which looks pretty normal, but still has one tail cut out (nevertheless simple rejection of negative outputs from generator is a fair way to deal with it).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. LOL! My new implementation for NormalDistribution looks a lot like I'd taken a slice of that code project and focused on just normal random numbers. I've got the same abstract classes for RNG's and Distribution's. I've got just one concrete RNG that uses the .NET Random class, and a concrete NormalDistribution class.

Comment: But as I can see they are not overloading Microsoft's original, so they can break the [0,1) limit.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You also might want to consider that perhaps you *don't* want a normally distributed variable on [0,1) but rather a random variable with a bell-shaped distribution naturally restricted to the [0,1) interval. If so, consider the [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) or the [Kumaraswamy distribution](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/11/24/kumaraswamy-distribution/).

Comment: I definitely want a normally distributed variable. I'll update the question with the specific problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible interpretation is that you are confusing "normal" and "uniform".  A uniform variate will have a mean of 0.5 and be evenly distributed on [0, 1).  If this interpretation is correct, your code simplifies to

```
return ranf()
```

Comment: I want to get a "normal" distribution with the appropriate hump at 0.5.

Comment: Then you won't be able to restrict it to the interval [0, 1).  As a practical matter, normal probabilities further out than about seven standard deviations are too small to be worth computing, anyway, so you could set the standard deviation to 1/2 / 7 = 1/14 = about 0.07.  This isn't too far from the value you found empirically.  With your value and enough draws, you are likely to get a number outside [0, 1); with 1/14, it's extremely unlikely.  Thus, my recommendation is to take a value from the Marsaglia algorithm, divide by 14, and add 1/2.  Adjust the 1/14 to suit your application.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the update you want to generate truncated normal random variables. Scaling based on the maximum and minimum will 'destroy' the normal distribution properties of the draws. Instead, you should consider using one of the two methods described below:

**[Rejection Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)**

You draw from the standard normal and then accept the draw only if it is between 0 and 1.

**[Inverse Transform Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)**

Let:

$\phi(x)$ be the standard normal cdf.

Then a standard normal draw that is restricted to lie between 0 and 1 is given by:

$x = \phi^{-1}(\phi(0) + (\phi(1) - \phi(0)) U )$

where

$U$ is a uniform random draw between 0 and 1.

Comment: For rejection sampling, what will I use as my g(x) and M value to simulate the normal distribution? For inverse transform sampling, do I use D Ibbetson's Algorithm 209 (http://old.sigchi.org/~perlman/stat/doc/z.c) to compute the cdf? What do I use as the inverse?

Comment: @Ants If I am right, you don't need a cannon like ITS.

Comment: For rejection sampling set f(x) ~ standard normal pdf I(0<x<1), g(x) ~ standard normal and and M=1. Your condition will then become select x if u < I(0<x<1) which is basically what I stated in my one line sentence above under rejection sampling.

Comment: @mbq: I don't get the ITS reference. I've been missing out on a lot of pop culture and current events references the past few months.

Comment: @Ants ITS=Inverse Transform Sampling